# AppAuth-iOS fails using OpenID 2.0 and Forgerock

Tags: ios, authentication, openid, appauth, forgerock

I am trying to use [this library (AppAuth-iOS)](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) to authenticate via Forgerock using OpenID authentication 2.0.

When I run [this sample app](https://github.com/jchnxu/TestOIDAppAuth-iOS), choosing "Authorize auto" I manage to authenticate the user in Forgerock but then I get the following error:

[image]

Looking at the debug error it says the following:

> Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.general Code=-4 \"(null)\"

This is the method that it is being called (credit: method taken from the app sample code that I linked above):

```
@IBAction func authWithAutoCodeExchange(_ sender: Any) {

    let issuer = URL(string: kIssuer)
    let redirectURI = URL(string: kRedirectURI)

    logMessage(format: "Fetching configuration for issuer: %@", issuer!.absoluteString)

    // discovers endpoints
    OIDAuthorizationService.discoverConfiguration(forIssuer: issuer!, completion: { (config, error) in
        if config == nil {
            self.logMessage(format: "Error retrieving discovery document: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            self.authState = nil
            return
        }

        self.logMessage(format: "Got configuration: %@", config!.description)

        // builds authentication request
        let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: config!, clientId: kClientID, scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID], redirectURL: redirectURI!, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)

        // performs authentication request
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.logMessage(format: "Initiating authorization request with scope: %@", request.scope!)
        appDelegate.currentAuthFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: { (authState, error) in
            if authState != nil {
                self.authState = authState
                self.logMessage(format: "Got authorization tokens. Access token: %@", (authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)!)
            } else {
                self.authState = nil
                self.logMessage(format: "Authorization error: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    })

}
```

Any idea on whether this is a client error or a Forgerock side configuration error?

Comment: "State mismatch" indicates that Forgerock is not sending back a state parameter that matches your request. If Forgerock does not support the state parameter (which they _should_ to be considered OAuth2 compliant), you can redact the autogenerated state from your request before sending it.

Comment: @mm24 did you resolve this issue?